# I can click but cannot move my cursor

Tags: windows-8, mouse-cursor

I'm running Windows 8.1, and my mouse has suddenly developed an issue. Specifically, the cursor is invisible, and can't be moved. I can click, but not move the cursor. I have tried my mouse in other Windows 8.1 PCs and it worked fine, so it's not the mouse at fault.

I have seen other posts with similar issues, but the people had problems with their mouse. It worked fine yesterday, but suddenly it stopped working today. I haven't installed anything or made any kind of changes recently.

Comment: If the cursor is invisible, how do you know it can't move? Are all the clicks in the same spot? If so, where?

Comment: Is this a laptop or PC? Try a different mouse either way. Or, if possible, use a different USB port for the mouse

Comment: Wow, this brings back memories.  The last time this happened to me, I was 10 and it was on my Win95, which my father had a "you break it you fix it policy".  I learned how to do everything using keyboard-only by trial and error over the course of two years before I managed to fix it.  Unfortunately, I can't remember what the fix was at the moment.

Comment: This isn't a question, it's a FYI.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it isn't a question and obsolete.

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurred because of microsoft automatic updates or other software/driver automatic updates.

Please get the latest version of mouse driver and install it.

Comment: OP states " I haven't installed anything or made any kind of changes recently. "

Comment: @Dave   Some updates done in background.

Answer (score 0):

This happened with my mouse. I uninstalled the mouse driver in Device Manager and unplugged the mouse and then I plugged in back into the USB port. It was auto detected and then it worked fine after that.